# undefined method `length' for #<Subproject:0x007faca1e4a318>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is wrong here? I'm getting this error:

> undefined method `length' for #<Subproject:0x007faca1e4a318>

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
 default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def changeDate_email(user, nameOfSubproject)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Your Projects", body: nameOfSubproject)
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Undefined method 'length' for what? And where does this error point to?

Comment: undefined method `length' for #<Subproject:0x007faca1e4a318>

Comment: You probably pass whole `Subproject` object as `nameOfSubproject` instead of passing only its name. BTW following ruby conventions, your variable should be named `name_of_subproject`.

Comment: It still makes no sense, to be honest - you want your email body to be name of subproject? So why do you set `@url` and `@user` instance variables?

Comment: I'm just a beginner in Ruby's world :P

Comment: I need    user for mail but for    url you are right

Comment: So you still don't have to set `@user` instance variable. You can do: `mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Your Projects', body: name_of_subproject)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class of nameOfSubProject, i am unsure of. Did you check that your nameOfSubProject parameter refers to sub_project.name or sub_project.get_email_html that returns a String?

Answer (score 0):

As body you have to pass an string... You are passing a SubProject object and that is why rails is complaining.

I have to say that the way that you are using the mailer is not the best one.

I recommend you to read the [action mailer rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to learn the way ActionMailer is meant to be used.

You can find more guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/